# Issue while creating dynamic framework in Swift with carthage

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, ios-frameworks, carthage

Hi Can any one help in resolving this issue.

I have created a dynamic framework in swift. My framework is referring some external frameworks like alamofire, xcglogger etc into my framework project. I am using carthage for this purpose.

It works perfectly. But when I create the framework and use it in another project its giving me error on my framework

> Missing required modules : 'Alamofire','XCGlogger'

Can anyone help me in this.

I am using carthage 0.16.2
xcode 7.3.1
Swift

Comment: check the dependency is correct/valid or not

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply, but can you be little more specific